# Using java How to print all values entered by user as soon as user stops entering values

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, break

Am a newbie to Java am using eclipse. i need to take unknown length of pair of input values when user stops giving input it should sort list based on key values and print all of them as soon as user stops entering values. my only problem is how to break while loop when user stops giving input . can some one please help me out

Input:(Unknown length)

1 2
3 5
2 4
8 9
6 7

--> when user stops giving input i.e pressing enter without values
 it should give output

output:

1 2
3 5
2 4
8 9
6 7

java code: --> my problem is How to break while loop here

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> dic = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> dic1 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();


    try{
        while(in!=null){

        dic.put(in.nextInt(),in.nextInt());

         }

    catch(Exception e){

    }


    list1.addAll(dic.keySet());
    Collections.sort(list1);
    for(int x: list1){

        dic1.put(x, dic.get(x));

    }

    for (int i : list1){

        System.out.println(i +" ,  " +dic1.get(i));
    }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the length of input, and if less than 1, you can break the loop.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List list = new ArrayList();
        String tmp="";
        while(true)
        {
            tmp=input.nextLine();
            if(tmp.length() > 0)
            list.add(tmp);
            else
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> dic = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> dic1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    try {
        String input = "";
        while (in != null && !((input = in.nextLine()).equals(""))) {

        Scanner parse = new Scanner(input);
        dic.put(parse.nextInt(), parse.nextInt());

        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {

    }

    // rest of the code

    }
}
```

After taking the input, it checks whether the input is an empty string or not. If it is, that means that it is the end of the input.

To capture the input it passes the `input` string into another scanner `parse` so that you can you `nextInt()` functionality of the scanner.